# iframe height size on 100%

Tags: wordpress, iframe

I know that there are a lot of questions about this subject, but I tried them all without a solve.

I want to insert an iframe (or embed object, I don't have any problem for this) and I am trying to make the div where the iframe is inside the perfect height where I won't have any scrollbar.

The problem is that I don't have access in the `<head>`. It is a WordPress and I don't have access on the theme.

Here is what I have done until now

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var sheet = document.createElement('style')
sheet.innerHTML = "html, .entry{height: 100%;} #content{height: 100%;} .post-1631{height: 100%;} .page{height: 100%;} .padder{height: 100%;} .row{height: 100%;} .container{height: 100%;} body{height: 100%;}";
document.head.appendChild(sheet);
</script>

<iframe src="http://..........com"  width="100%" height="100%">
</iframe>
```

Inside the JavaScript, I change all the parent tags to `height:100%` until the head. I don't know if it is right, but I thought that I must change them all. Any suggestion?

**Problem 2:** As I was trying to solve the initial problem, I found another one, but I don't want to open a new question just for this. The embed page has many `<a href="#div-id"></a>` This mean that when I click on this link, I would redirected to the div with that id in the same page. But unfortunately, this doesn't work. I click on the link but nothing happend.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that works for me -- I have no recollection where I found it previously, so sorry for not properly attributing it!  You may have to tweak it a bit for the context you are using it on.

```
function sizeFrame() {
    var F = document.getElementById("YourFrameIdGoesHere");
    if (F.contentDocument) {
        F.height = F.contentDocument.documentElement.scrollHeight + 80; //FF 3.0.11, Opera 9.63, and Chrome
    } else {
        F.height = F.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 80; //IE6, IE7 and Chrome
    }
}

window.onload = sizeFrame;
```

Comment: I add an id to iFrame and also add the same id on the javascript, but unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood the question.  You are not trying to resize the IFRAME, but the div that contains the IFRAME.  We knew in advance the MAX height of the content in the IFRAME, so our containing div was properly sized to prevent the scrollbar.  If the content of your IFRAME is dynamic and you do not know the height in advance, that will definitely be more challenging.  Good luck!